# Android Polling using AlarmManager

Tags: android, background, alarmmanager, polling

I'm trying to set up an alarm that runs in the background (even if the app isn't running) that will poll our server every 2 minutes and check for updates.  If there is an update, I want to send the user a notification.

I've spent countless hours researching solutions and I can't seem to get this to work.  Right now, when the user enters the background, I manually fire an alarm after 5 seconds but all it does is launch the app instead of checking for the updates:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm_mgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm_mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 5000, pending_intent);
```

Is this even possible with the latest SDK? How do I get my alarm to run in the background? Thanks.

Comment: What does "launch the app" mean? What is the code for `NotificationAlarm`?

Comment: My app opens to my first activity. NotificationAlarm is my BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: If `NotificationAlarm` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, then your above code will not work, as a `BroadcastReceiver` cannot be used with a `getService()` `PendingIntent`.